# Doctrine case sensitivity in schema.yml

Tags: php, doctrine

Doctrine turns my column names into all lower case to improve compatibility.  How do I prevent this from happening?

```
users:
  actAs: [Timestampable]
  columns:
    userId:
      type: integer
      length: 4
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
```

or

```
$this->hasColumn('userId', 'integer', 4, array(
         'type' => 'integer',
         'length' => 4,
         'primary' => true,
         'autoincrement' => true,
         ));
```

then becomes

```
userid
```

This is a problem because I have lots of existing code and data that uses the camelCase convention.  Is there some sort of easy boolean I can change to make it keep my columns exactly as written?

Answer (score 2):

The Yaml conversion is where the issue lies. To fix this you need to alias the column name in the YAML schema file IE: name: user_id as userId